# json_decode in php returns in unexpected form

Tags: php, json

When using json_decode I am getting fields with unexpected strings.
My json file is:

```
{
buyer_accepts_marketing: false,
cart_token: "eeafa272cebfd4b22385bc4b645e762c",
id: 327474488104976400,
}
```

and my relevant php code is

```
$info = json_decode($file,true);
print $info["id"];
echo "<br>";
print $info["cart_token"];
```

The Output I am getting is

**3.2747448810498E+17**

**eeafa272cebfd4b22385bc4b645e762c**

Why am I not getting the correct value of id?

Comment: Is this value coming from DB, I mean is a service bringing this data.?

Comment: To be exact, the json file was generated by a shopify webhook.

Comment: id: "327474488104976400". Just change the file.

Comment: The id type is an integer and the current value exceeds the integer range.

Comment: do a cast to string, as the value is a float although is looks like an integer

Comment: The range of Integer is [-2147483648, 2147483647] and the id value here exceeds it!+

Comment: @jewelnguyen8 what do u meant by 'change the file' ?

Comment: The gist: more recent PHP versions allow for `JSON_BIGINT_AS_STRING`.

Comment: Tkz evryone.. Using preg_replace solved the problem.

Answer (score 0):

It happening because the value of `id` is out of the range. Try to create it as string. if it is changed to string then it will work properly.

`Integer overflow`

```
If PHP encounters a number beyond the bounds of the integer type, it will be interpreted as a float instead. Also, an operation which results in a number beyond the bounds of the integer type will return a float instead.
```

Comment: Tkz.. preg_replace was the best solution.